# IntelliJ Idea: org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.modelgen.CanonicalModelProcessor not found

Tags: java, debugging, maven, jpa, intellij-idea

We have Maven projects with Eclipselink 2.5.1 integration. Unit tests using IntelliJ stop working for me with error:

> Error:java: error: Annotation processor
>   'org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.modelgen.CanonicalModelProcessor'
>   not found

But it worked for me with Eclipselink 2.3 and still working using maven commands.

May be somebody have solution for this issue?

Comment: If you have CanonicalModelProcessor issues with running junit tests in Idea 13 just open Settings->Compiler->Annotation Processors and make sure that Processor FQ Name is empty for every project.